# Getting Error while using pysvn:propget()

Tags: svn, pysvn

In My python script i Called propget() API,

```
     root = "...."
     prop_list = svncl.propget( "Test",
     root,
     revision=pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, 42),
     recurse=False,
     peg_revision=pysvn.Revision( pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, 42 ),
     depth="empty" )
```

But getting following error while running the script,

**TypeError: propget() cannot mix depth and recurse**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_propget) says: "The depth can be used as in place of recurse."

You seem to be using both depth and recurse. Try removing one.